# How do I find the equation of a tangent and the normal given one point on a circle?

Tags: circles, education, tangent-line

How do I find an equation of the tangent and the normal at the point $(1, -2)$ on the circle $x^2 + y^2 = 5$?

Comment: Hi, Can you find $\frac{dy}{dx}$ from the equation of the circle?

Answer (score 1):

The normal line passes through the given point $(1,-2)$ and the centre of the circle $(0,0)$, that is $y=-2x$.

The tangent line passes through the given point $(1,-2)$ and it is orthogonal to the normal line. Hence we obtain $y=\frac{1}{2}(x-1)-2$.

Answer (score 0):

Differentiate the equation w.r.t x,
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{-x}{y}$$
Putting $(1,-2)$,
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{1}{2}$$
Now, you got slope and a point.Apply point slope form,
$$(y+2)=0.5(x-1)$$
This is the equation of tangent. $$$$
Since, the tangent is perpendicular to normal; therefore, 
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{y}{x}$$
Putting $(1,-2)$,
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{-2}{1}$$
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=-2$$
Apply point slope form,
$$(y+2)=-2(x-1)$$
This is the equation of Normal.

Answer (score 0):

Start with
$$
y=-\sqrt{5-x^2}.
$$
Then
$$
\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{x}{\sqrt{5-x^2}}.
$$
At the point $(1,-2)$, the slope of the tangent line is
$$
m_t=\frac{1}{\sqrt{5-1^2}}=1/2.
$$
The desired tangent line is
$$
y+2=\frac{1}{2}(x-1)
$$
which yields
$$
x-2y-5=0.
$$
For the normal line we have
$$
y+2=-2(x-1)
$$
which yields
$$
2x+y=0.
$$